# iTunes won't show artwork after I copy my music files from my old mac to another mac

Tags: itunes

I copy my music files from my old mac to my new mac and iTunes won't show artwork.
[image: artwork]

Each song still has its own artwork, just iTunes won't show it. I googled it and some said delete the cache folder inside artwork folder. But it doesn't work for me.

Any other suggestion ?

[image: door artwork]

Comment: How did you copy your songs? generally you should just copy the whole iTunes music folder

Comment: Yes I copy the whole folder